# Find total number of topic in kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have a kafka cluster with 3 brokers, I would like to know the total number of topics in the cluster.

Is there a script or any command to find out the total.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to find this out:

- AdminClient API: You can use [`listTopics()`](http://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#listTopics--) and just call `size()` on [`names()`](http://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/ListTopicsResult.html#names--).
- `kafka-topics.sh` tool: You can use `./kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost --list | wc -l`.

---

A topic is just a group of partitions. For Kafka it's the same if you have 1 topics with 10 partitions or 10 topics with 1 partition each. However, 10 topics with 1 partitions is not the same as 10 topics with 10 partitions each. That's why, in practice, you are usually interested in the number of partitions.

To count partitions:

- Metrics: Brokers expose a [metric](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#monitoring) called `kafka.server:type=ReplicaManager,name=PartitionCount`
- `kafka-topics.sh` tool: You can use `./kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost --describe | grep "Partition:" | wc -l`
- AdminClient API: You first need to get the topic list (via `listTopics()`) and then call `describeTopics()`. The number of partitions for each topic is available in the [`TopicDescription`](http://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/TopicDescription.html) object you get back.

Comment: "kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --topic '.*202012.*' | grep PartitionCount | wc -l"


I find this more helpful if looking for a specific type of topics using regex. As far as I can see, the --list command doesn't seem to support regex.